# asp.net - web frontend to managing database table - add, delete, update

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have a database table that i want to allow my friends to update.  What is the quickest way to have a asp.net page that is simply a form that maps to every field in the database and allows for add, deletes, and updates.  I assume there should be an out of the box solution for this without having to code up each control, etc . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET dynamic data. Build a data model, that's about it. Create a custom template if you want to.

http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/